# getting a total value of array over a loop, python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop which generates an array from a text file. Every time it passes through the loop I want it to add the new array to the old one but I'm not sure how to do this. For example:

```
loop=np.arange(1,50)
for arg in loop:
   str(arg)
   a=np.genfromtxt('dir/'+arg+'.txt').T[0]
total=a+a+a #I know this line is wrong
```

How do I get total to be the total of every a over the array loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the arrays you get from the text have a fixed length? If yes, reading the first array and then doing in-place summation should work:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('dir1.txt').T[0]

loop=np.arange(2, 50)
for arg in loop:
    str(arg)
    a += np.genfromtxt('dir'+arg+'.txt').T[0]
```

If your arrays have different lengths weird problems might happen when numpy tries to guess how to do the additions.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add the arrays you get while reading in a loop can't you add the array to total each time in the loop:

```
loop=np.arange(1,50)
total = []
for arg in loop:
   str(arg)
   a=np.genfromtxt('dir/'+arg+'.txt').T[0]
   total+=a (or total.append(a))
```